# Create MySql database with TEXT column

Tags: c#, mysql, database, remote-server, mysql.data

I'm creating MySql database table from C# desktop application on remote server. I would like to make long records for columns content. I guess TEXT type must be suitable for this, but I'm not sure, how to set it from my `createTableQuery` string, instead `varchar(120)`:

```
string createTableQuery = string.Format(@"CREATE TABLE `{0}` (
   `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `slots` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `vectors` varchar(120) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `id` (`id`)) 
   ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;", "tab");
```

Or maybe I should use some different type...

Any advice and example would be useful

Comment: Please [see here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/understanding-strorage-sizes-for-mysql-text-data-types/) for a description of the text storage options in MySQL.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Thank you so longtext should be a TEXT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be:

```
string createTableQuery = string.Format(@"CREATE TABLE `{0}` (
`id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`slots` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`vectors` TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id` (`id`)) 
ENGINE = MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;", "tab");
```

Comment: Ok, so just this way... Thank you